# Database provisioning practices under IaC

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I'm working on a project consists of an api application (AWS API Gateway + AWS Lambda) and a database (AWS DynamoDB). I use Terraform and GitLab CI to automate deployment for this project. When I modify the API Gateway config or Lambda function to fix bugs, I need to re-deploy the whole system (probably including DynamoDB) by executing `terraform apply`. This may cause data loss because DynamoDB may be re-created. I want to release a new version api without changing database in CI/CD pipeline. In my understanding, `terraform apply -target=xxx` is suitable for a small system, but not suitable for a complex one.

I wonder if there any best practices for database provisioning using IaC. Is it better to treat database separately and tracked in an entirely different system? Do I need to implement database backup and migration in my CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: Terraform Apply doesn't delete or recreate resource which have not updated or changed, can you let me know when you fix the bug in lambda or API gateway, do you also modify the configuration of database. As in ideal scenario if you are not updating anything in your database, Terraform will ignore database and will modify/delete/create only those resource which has been changed.

Comment: For now, no. I assumed that db config might also be modified in some cases. By the way, I want to adopt GitOps, only one entry point to manage the API and database. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when using IaC, Database is not something which gets modified as frequently as application deployments. Even when you deploy (update) Lambda + API-Gateway, you're not touching DB and `terraform apply` should not modify the "connection" between App layer and Data layer. Even if it does, try not to "re-create" database and pass all the configs from IaC itself.

If your use-case has to destroy database and re-create then you have to automate backup of data somewhere and load it into DB after provisioning. This is going to be a pain in the back very soon. Recreating database is not ideal, backups take time, and reloading data is costly (data transfers) and SLOW!

Maybe you should re-architect your IAC strategy where you don't have to re-create DB a lot. Updating small configs should not be a problem as configs will be passed around via IaC (app layer to DB layer & vice versa)

Comment: Nice concept, thanks! I should re-design my IaC strategy. Do you recommend that separate database from api application and version-control database in different project? Or managing api and database in the same project like [this](https://tree.nathanfriend.io/?s=(%27options!(%27fancy!true~fullPath!false~trailingSlash!true~rootDot!false)~2(%272%27api-application0api*database*.gitlab-ci.yml%27)~version!%271%27)*%20%7Bterraform%20project%7D03main.tf00%5Cn32source!3%20%20%01320*). Have 2 terraform entry points in the same project. The communication between 2 terraform sub-project maybe a problem.

Comment: If you don't want 1 project then you can create 2 modules in terraform for your app and data layer. 2 different TF projects will be overkill and demand more management & context knowledge later on.